# How can I access the following element, with watir. I always get error

Tags: javascript, html, css, watir

How can I access the following element, with watir. I always get error.

```
 <div style="visibility: visible;"><div id="nav">
    <div id="nav-toggle"></div>
        <ul id="itens-menu">

            <li>
                <a href="#cartao-01">
                    <i class="icon-table"></i>ponto 01</a>
            </li>

            <li class="ativo">
                <a href="#batidas-02">
                    <i class="icon-clock"></i>Inclusão de Ponto</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#calculadora-03">
                    <i class="icon-calculator"></i>Calculator</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

I'm trying something like:

```
site = Watir::Browser.start(SITE1, :chrome)

site.ul(:id => "itens-menu").li(:class => "ativo").i(:class => "icon-clock").click
```

How can I click this element?

```
<i class = "icon-clock"> </ i> I
```

in the above example structure

Comment: Could you please provide the exception that you are getting? Knowing the error would give more ideas for why the exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried waiting for the element present before interacting?

```
site.element(class: "icon-clock").wait_until(timeout = 30, &:present?).click
```

Alternatively you can use fireevent to click

```
site.element(class: "icon-clock").wait_until(timeout = 30, &:present?).fire_event :click
```

'timeout' is optional, wait_until will wait for watir default timeout which is 5 secs.
Here I am waiting for 30 sec in my above sample code.

Comment: Waiting is automatic in watir

Comment: Your remark was perfect @supputuri, your suggestion solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks, please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark below the down vote on the left hand site in my answer.

Comment: By accepting the answer, the question will be moved out from the unanswered bucket in SO. So, please do this for cleanup purpose.